# OWIN TestServer authorization fails when running on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, asp.net-web-api2, owin

I have a WebApi application which uses OWIN bearer token authorization. This is being unit-tested with OWIN TestServer. Test is very simple: it creates 10 simultaneous authorization requests to server and verifies that every request receives its response.

Tests are running fine on my dev machine but fail on Amazon Web Services with following stack trace:

```
MESSAGE:
System.AggregateException : One or more errors occurred.
  ----> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException : Access is denied.

+++++++++++++++++++
STACK TRACE:
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
at MyTestMethod()
--CryptographicException
at System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData.Protect(Byte[] userData, Byte[] optionalEntropy, DataProtectionScope scope)
at System.Security.Cryptography.DpapiDataProtector.ProviderProtect(Byte[] userData)
at Microsoft.Owin.Security.DataHandler.SecureDataFormat`1.Protect(TData data)
at Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.OAuthAuthorizationServerHandler.<InvokeTokenEndpointAsync>d__22.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.OAuthAuthorizationServerHandler.<InvokeAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.Owin.Testing.OwinClientHandler.<>c__DisplayClass1.<<SendAsync>b__0>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
at Microsoft.Owin.Testing.OwinClientHandler.<SendAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
```

Google search on the problem does not give exact matches.

**Test method:**

```
    public void MyTestMethod()
    {
        const int loginNumber = 10;
        List<Tuple<string, string>> userList = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();

        for (int i = 0; i < loginNumber; ++i)
            userList.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("SomeName", "SomePassword"));

        using (var server = TestServer.Create<Startup>())
        {
            var loginTasks = userList.Select(item => server.CreateRequest("/token").And(x => x.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", item.Item1),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", item.Item2),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "password")
            })).PostAsync());

            HttpResponseMessage[] loginTasksResults = Task.WhenAll(loginTasks).Result; // AggregatedException here

            // ...
        }
    }
```

**Startup class**

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        ConfigureOAuth(app);

        HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
        WebApiConfig.Register(config);
        app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);

        NinjectWebCommon.Start();
        config.DependencyResolver = new NinjectDependencyResolver(NinjectWebCommon.bootstrapper.Kernel);

        app.UseWebApi(config);
        app.MapSignalR();
    }

    public void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
        {
            AllowInsecureHttp = true,
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
            Provider = new MyAuthorizationProvider()
        };

        // Token Generation
        app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthServerOptions);
        app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());
    }
}
```

**Authorization Provider**

```
public class MyAuthorizationProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
{
    public override async Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
    {
        context.Validated();
    }

    public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
        context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { "*" });

        if (context.UserName == null || context.Password == null)
        {
            context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is empty.");
            return;
        }

        string authenticationId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("n");

        ClaimsIdentity oAuthIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);
        oAuthIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, context.UserName));
        oAuthIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("sub", context.UserName));
        oAuthIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("role", "user"));
        oAuthIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("auth_id", authenticationId));

        context.Validated(oAuthIdentity);
    }
}
```